# Concatenating files in a mockable/testable way

Tags: python, unit-testing, io, mocking

I have a use case where I have a bunch of files which I need to concatenate sequentially, deleting each file after it's been concatenated to the output. The code looks something like this:

```
def compile(self):
    with open("output.file", "wb") as outfile:
        for part in sorted(self.parts):
            with open(part, "rb") as infile:
                for line in infile:
                    outfile.write(line)

            os.remove(part)

    # do other logic ...
```

I'm having a hard time coming up with a way to test this code properly. I want to establish that:

1. The parts are sorted and looped over in sorted order.
2. Each input file is read line by line and written to the output file.
3. Each input file is removed after exhausted.

My main difficulty is in mocking the file objects. I'm using Python's `mock` library, but I'm not sure where to patch and how to accomplish it. How can I patch the file objects to ensure that everything was written properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really want to test that 'open', 'os.remove', 'sorted' are actually working, it's safe to assume that since they are part of the python standard lib, that they've been heavily tested elsewhere.  All you really want is to test that they actually get called, so you can simply mock those calls in your test code and test that they are actually called with the args that you expect.

A test could be something like

```
@mock.patch.object(os, 'remove')
@mock.patch('%s.sorted' % __name__, create=True)
@mock.patch('%s.open' % __name__, create=True)
def test_compile(mock_open, mock_sort, mock_os_remove):
    mock_sort.return_value = ['parts']
    compile()
    mock_open.assert_any_call('output.file', 'wb')
    mock_sorted.assert_called_with(['parts'])
    mock_os_remove.assert_called_with('parts','rb')
```

Obviously this will have to be adjusted a bit as compile() appears to be a method rather than a stand alone function, but the patches and general approach to the function should be the same.